# Add a Facebook like button to a Mediawiki page

Tags: facebook, mediawiki, facebook-iframe

I am editing a page on a local [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) install.

I would like to know if it is possible to embed a Facebook like button on a page in the wiki?

I don't have administrator rights, so I can't install any extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a completely internal installation, you could [enable raw html](http://perassi.org/2008/02/01/inserting-raw-html-code-in-mediawiki/) in the config file but this could be a big security risk if it is a public wiki.

Comment: It is a public facing wiki, but the editing is restricted to trusted contributors only, so I think I can take the risk.